# Is it possible to know which function threw the error when running db.SaveChanges in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We want to store our errors in a database table so we can find where things went wrong when our project is in production. We want to catch errors that happen when running `db.SaveChanges()`. We can't run a debugger in production so this is our answer to be able to save our errors.

So far I have this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        var errorMessages = e.EntityValidationErrors
                .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

        // Join the list to a single string.
        var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

        // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
        var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(e.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

        // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
        throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, e.EntityValidationErrors);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        Exception realerror = ex;

        while (realerror.InnerException != null)
            realerror = realerror.InnerException;

        Console.WriteLine(realerror.ToString());
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I was trying something like this to catch the errors whenever `SaveChanges()` is run that way it is in one spot. Is there a way to know which function called that `SaveChanges()` so I can save that in the database so we can see where it failed or at least the line number it was called on?

I know that I can add a `try-catch` to every function and catch it and save it that way with the function that it had the error, but I was hoping to just be able to have it in one spot for simplicity.

Comment: What kind of app is this? WPF? Winforms? Website? Something else?

Comment: use stack trace to find which method call savechange

Comment: When handling an exception and raising another, attach the original exception in as the InnerException of the new one. When re-throwing an exception to be handled, use "throw" not "throw(ex)" as the latter will reset the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Caller Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information)

If you want the name of the Method that called you, the file in which this method is declared  and the line number, do something like this:

```
public void SaveChanges(string message,  
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string callerMethod = "",  
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFile = "",  
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)  
{
    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }  
    catch (...)
    {
         // here you can use callerMethod, sourceFile, lineNumber
         // as string in your diagnostic message
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
     ...
     dbContext.SaveChanges(); // all parameters are optional!
}
```

You must specify an explicit default value for each optional parameter. You can't apply Caller Info attributes to parameters that aren't specified as optional.

The Caller Info attributes don't make a parameter optional. Instead, they affect the default value that's passed in when the argument is omitted.

Caller Info values are emitted as literals into the Intermediate Language (IL) at compile time. Unlike the results of the StackTrace property for exceptions, the results aren't affected by obfuscation.

In the rare case that you don't want the default values you can explicitly name them:

```
void ChangeCity(string city)
{
    ...
    DbContext.SaveChanges($"{nameof(ChangeCity)} where city = {city}");
}
```